# Kafka Connect: SMT for conditional replacement of field values

Tags: apache-kafka, transformation, apache-kafka-connect

I know there are transform actions available for example `MaskField` to mask fields value. I have a requirement where I need to do conditional masking i.e set value to `NULL` only if the same field has a specific value. For example:

```
IF field_1 == 'HELLO' THEN
 SET field_1 = null
ELSE
 NO TRANSFORM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no currently any SMT that supports the conditional replacement of a field value.

---

You can however, write your own Single Message Transform as described [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/custom.html#custom-transform).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could also use something like ksqlDB to do this easily

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I agree. I mentioned the custom transformation in case somebody wants to do it through Kafka Connect.